# An automated loop & code execution steps in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am a beginner to Python. I am nearly completed my booking automation but am struggling with the loop.

Basically the booking will open at 18:00 but I need the browser.get url is to keep refreshing until the booking opens and it can execute the below XX piece of code.

```
browser.get('https://')
while False:( have just put this false in to show what im trying or on the right path, or not!!!)
browser. Refresh()

XX = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='booking_form_1']"))
XX.select_by_index(1)
XX.select_by_visible_text('XXXXXX')
```

What's the simplest way?

Comment: When the booking opens, can you get the open message? Then you can stop the loop right? For example, `booking_open = False while not booking_open:loop... until booking_open = XX.get_booking_msg() #return True `, Then the loop would stop.

Comment: i get a pop up screen that says  time unavailable
You cannot book the chosen time. Please select another

Comment: but then the errors in my pycharm log show the below:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C
    xx = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='booking_player_1']"))

 File "C:\PycharmProjects\1stPython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)

Comment: File "C:\\PycharmProjects\1stPython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "\PycharmProjects\1stPython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

Comment: File "C:\PycharmProjects\1stPython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='booking_player_1']"}

Comment: my code works ok when the booking is open and all automates ok.

Comment: there is no message when the booking opens it just let me choose the time available and no pop up message as above from the website

Comment: would the loop close when the popup does not show 
pop up = class" swal2-popup swal2-modal swal2-show"

Comment: In fact, `u get a pop up screen that says time unavailable You cannot book the chosen time. Please select another` —— this is the msg that booking has not started yet, you should be able to get it. On the contrary, if you don’t get a pop up, the booking has started.

Comment: how does that set out in code format with the loop #newbie

Comment: I wrote the answer to loop below, but the `get_open_msg` function needs you to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```py
browser.get('https://')
is_booking_open = False
while not is_booking_open:
    browser. Refresh()

    XX = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='booking_form_1']"))
    XX.select_by_index(1)
    XX.select_by_visible_text('XXXXXX')
    is_booking_open = get_open_msg() #return True or False; You need to determine whether there is a not opening pop up, selenium can do that
```

Comment: thanks very much, how does selenium determine if pop up or not

Comment: Just like this function `find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='booking_form_1']")`, when pop up, there must be some HTML elements that can be obtained, such as `<class='xxxx active>'`, `active` is the msg that you can determine. The specific situation depends on how the booking website is designed.